# Python arguments to variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, arguments

I am new to python and working on putting arguments into variables. I was trying to only allow three variables as arguments and put them into `a`, `b` and `c` as a string.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

x = sys.argv[1:]
x = ' '.join(x)
if len(x) > 3:
        print "Only three arguments"
else:
        print "Too many arguments"
a,b,c=[[y] for y in x.split()]
print a
print b
print c
```

Comment: Why that's print "Too many arguments" if there's less 3???

Comment: Are you expecting *exactly* 3 arguments, or *up to* 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the arguments as scalars, you don't need the `[]` around `y`:

```
a,b,c = [y for y in x.split()]
```

But frankly, you don't even need to go through the joining a splitting - you can assign an array to a series of comma-delimited scalars:

```
a,b,c = sys.argv[1:]
```

Similarly, you shouldn't check `len` on a joined string, but on the array. A complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

x = sys.argv[1:] # no joining!
if len(x) == 3:
    print "Only three arguments"
    a,b,c = x
    print a
    print b
    print c
else:
    print "Too many arguments"
```

Comment: Oh right, thanks! How can I test with a if to check that it's only three arguments and not less ore more.

Comment: You can just check `len(sys.argv)`.

Comment: @Iknowpython you can use the `==` operator. See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if len(sys.argv)!=4:
    print "Need to get 3 arguments"
    sys.exit()

a=str(sys.argv[1])
b=str(sys.argv[2])
c=str(sys.argv[3])
print a
print b
print c
```

Comment: If I enter four arguments I get "Only three arguments" thats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code:

```
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
if len(args) > 3:
        print "Too many arguments"

for arg in args:
    print(arg)
```